# Wordpress: How to get a response from a wordpress function in Json?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, function

Hello I am creating an api for wordpress which I will access from my android device but the functions mentioned on this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference
return only plain text. For me to be able to handle the result returned I want the result to be in JSON format. Please tell me how do I convert the response returned in JSON. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to make an ajax call. Send some kind of request from you application, like this:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_handler&id=123
```

Then put this code into your function.php (or into a plugin) to catch it and send a json response. This example will return the content of a post:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_handler', 'my_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_handler', 'my_handler');

function my_handler() {

  $post_id = $_GET['id'];

  $post_content = get_post($post_id)->post_content; // do something with WP API.

  $response = array('content' => $post_content);

  echo json_encode($response);
  die();

}
```

Check https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins for more details.